# Using Reactjs frontend on iPad 2012 Chrome v59

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, ipad

Im trying to get my reactjs frontend running on my iPad and Android phone browsers. The main index.html opens but without stays blank with no errors shown.

I cannot find which version of packages to use for this. The frontend right now only loads on desktop browsers.

My environment:

- iPad 2012 edition using iOS 9.3.5.
- Reactjs 15.5
- Webpack 2.6
- Babel 6.24

(PlexTV also uses reactjs frontend and also works fantastic on mobile browsers too.)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the `.js` file not getting loaded in the mobile browsers.

I'm not sure about how you could test this on iOS, but you could try [Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) using your Android phone to see for any errors in the Console or Network tab of Developer Tools.